# Как установить Node.js 5.5 в CentOs 6.7

Tags: node.js, centos

есть ssh доступ к серверу на CentOs 6.7, хочу установить Node.js v5.5? но на официальном сайте нашел где просто скачать установщик. кто то может подсказать как установить через командную строку?

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается по [инструкции](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora) с официального сайта?

Comment: не получается поставить последнюю версию а именно v5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может кому то это пригодится. На самом деле в `CentOs 6.7` не ставится новые версии `Node.js (v5.х)`, но можно с начало поставить старую версию а потом обновить с помощью следующих команд:

```
$ node -v 
  v0.10.37

$ sudo npm cache clean -f

$ sudo npm install -g n 

$ sudo n stable 

$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.0.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node

$ node -v 
   v5.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Действительно - на старый ContOS не ставятся новые версии NODEJS

Действия такие-
открываем CentOS
запускаем SHELL(выполнение команд пользователя)
   вводим команды и жмем ввод

> cd
>   curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
>   yum -y install nodejs
>   node -v

В конце покажет ответ как v4.4.7